# How to generate checkbox with json objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I am trying to generate checkboxes dynamically using json objects.

Controller

```
App.controller('amenitiesController',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
var location_id = $('#location_id').val();
$http({method: 'GET', url: "/api/location/"+location_id+".json"}).
success(function(data, status) {

    $.each(data.location.lodges, function(i,lodge) {
            $.each(lodge, function(key,fac){
                 $.each(fac.facilities, function(index,f){
                    $scope.facilityNames =  [ {name:f.facility.name,id:f.facility.id}];

                    console.log(f.facility.id,f.facility.name)
                });
            });
        });

}).
error(function(data, status) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
}]) ;
```

Html file

```
<div class='col-md-2 searchdisplay-col1' ng-controller="amenitiesController" style="margin-top:50px">
            <label ng-repeat="facilityName in facilityNames">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="{{facilityName.name}}"
                value="{{facilityName.id}}"
                ng-checked=""
                ng-click=""
              > {{facilityName.name}}
            </label>

        </div>
```

I get all the objects from json successfuly, but the checkbox is generated only for the last json object. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is in following line, Where you are re-initialize your array `$scope.facilityNames` with newly iterated facilty. You should declare an empty array before ajax request, then on iteration add `facility` to previously created array.

```
 $scope.facilityNames =  [ {name:f.facility.name,id:f.facility.id}];
```

*Modified Code*

```
$scope.facilityNames = []; //Initialize array
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "/api/location/" + location_id + ".json"
}).
success(function (data, status) {
    $.each(data.location.lodges, function (i, lodge) {
        $.each(lodge, function (key, fac) {
            $.each(fac.facilities, function (index, f) {
                //add facility to array
                $scope.facilityNames.push({
                    name: f.facility.name,
                    id: f.facility.id
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```